# How to pass JSON data from ChildComponent to AppComponent using EventEmitter in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, event-handling

I am trying to send productName and Quantity from product.component.ts to app.component.ts.I got productName in console as you can see in the output.But for the quantity its showing undefined.
And one more thing when i try to display products from app.component.ts in my template i get the error products is not defined in the app.component.ts

[Here is the product.component.ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFsa4.png)

[Here is my app.component.html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzbMG.png)
[Here is the app.component.ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fnghd.png)

Comment: Please don't add code as images. A minimal, reproducible example would be more helpful. You need to show the controller for both the components.

Answer (score 0):

Typo you are printing console.log(product.quantityy) it has to be console.log(product.quantity);

Could you please attach the template file ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the HTML file to see if you have some typos, but I built an example where simulates your example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-overflow-input-output